# R perform calculations on groups for subset of rows

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

In other words, I want to group on a column and then perform calculations using only some of the rows per group.

The data set I have is:

```
    LoanRefId               Tran_Type TransactionAmount
103        11               LoanIssue         1000.0000
104        11           InitiationFee          171.0000
105        11                Interest           59.6729
106        11       AdministrationFee           64.9332
107        11 RaisedClientInstallment         1295.5757
108        11       ClientInstallment         1295.4700
109        11                  PaidUp            0.0000
110        11              Adjustment            0.1361
111        11                  PaidUp            0.0000
112        12               LoanIssue         3000.0000
113        12           InitiationFee          399.0000
114        12                Interest           94.9858
115        12       AdministrationFee           38.6975
116        12 RaisedClientInstallment         3532.6350
117        12       ClientInstallment         3532.6100
118        12                  PaidUp            0.0000
119        12              Adjustment            0.0733
120        12                  PaidUp            0.0000
```

I would like to repeat the following calculation for each group:
`ClientInstallment` - `LoanIssue`.

So, group 1 will be for `LoanRefId` number 11. The calculation will take `ClientInstallment` of 1295.47 and subtract `LoanIssue` of 1000 to give me a new column, call it "Income, with value 295.47.

Is this possible using `data.table` or `dplyr` or any other clever tricks.

Alternatively I can create two data summaries, one for `Clientinstallment` and one for `LoanIssue` and then subtract them, but the truth is I need to do much more than just subtracting two numbers, so I would need a data summary for each calculation which is just plain unclever imho.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'LoanRefId', we get the corresponding 'TransactionAmount' for 'Tran_Type's 'ClientInstallment' and 'LoanIssue' and then subtract it.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[,list(Income =TransactionAmount[Tran_Type=='ClientInstallment']-
       TransactionAmount[Tran_Type=='LoanIssue']), by = LoanRefId]
#  LoanRefId Income
#1:        11 295.47
#2:        12 532.61
```

---

We can also use `dplyr` with similar appraoch

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(LoanRefId) %>%
    summarise(Income = TransactionAmount[Tran_Type=='ClientInstallment']-
                       TransactionAmount[Tran_Type=='LoanIssue'])
```

#### Update

If we don't have a 'ClientInstallment' or 'LoanIssue' for a 'LoanRefId', we can use an `if/else` condition

```
setDT(df1)[, list(Income= if(any(Tran_Type=='ClientInstallment') & 
              any(Tran_Type=='LoanIssue')) 
            TransactionAmount[Tran_Type=='ClientInstallment'] - 
            TransactionAmount[Tran_Type=='LoanIssue'] else 0 ), by = LoanRefId]
```

Comment: This works perfectly if there is always a row for "ClientInstallment" and "LoanIssue". When these rows are not available is causes the calc to break down returning 0 obs. Can you please advise how I can get around that, for e.g specify a default value when the row is not there? Essentially, if one of the rows is not available it should be 0 for that row.

Comment: @gmarais Okay, I understand the trouble.  We can use an `if/else` condition for that.

Comment: @gmarais Updated the post.  Please check if that works.  I didn't test it.